# Start a RunOnce application with administrator privileges

Tags: c++, windows, manifest, elevated-privileges

I have a program which, when installed, gets added to the `RunOnce` registry in Windows, so that it runs for the first time after Windows gets rebooted post installation.

This application installs a couple of Windows `.NET`services using `SC Create` string passed in `_wsystem`. Unfortunately it fails to install at least one service..

To eliminate all other conditions, I'd like this application to run as an elevated, privileged user.

This application is in `C++.` Should I add a manifest or something to achieve this?

Comment: Add windows tag also

Comment: Let the user Okay it. Don't bypass that user confirmation. I.e. don't use the `RunOnce`. In ordinary userland you can run an app elevated in many ways. At the API level use `ShellExecute` with `"runas"` action. For the command interpreter use a shortcut with elevation.

Comment: What if the next user to log on doesn't *have* administrative privileges?  You need to redesign.  The services should be created during installation, but if there's some bizarre reason why that's not possible, create a service whose job is to install the other services.